# Bit Banging UART

Tags: microcontroller, pic, serial, c, uart

My full code is located [here](http://pastebin.com/f70wPPKT).

Basically, I'm transmitting to an Arduino, and I'm not receiving the correct value (you'll notice I'm trying to send d'22'). Here's the method where I actually bit bang the transmission:

```
// Method for transmitting value using serial bit banging
void uart_tx_bit_bang(unsigned char val) {
    unsigned char i;
    Tx_Pin = 0;                         // Start bit
    uart_time_delay();
    for ( i = 8 ; i != 0 ; --i ) {
        if (val & 0x01) Tx_Pin = 1;   // Begin with LSB
        else            Tx_Pin = 0;
        val >>= 1;
        uart_time_delay();
        }
    Tx_Pin = 1;                         // Stop bit
    uart_time_delay();
}
```

Since the delay should be 1/baud, `uart_time_delay()` should be a 104us delay. I'm using `__delay_us(104)` from the PIC libraries. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

I'm positive that I'm using the correct baud rate on both ends.

Comment: UARTs actually send the LSB first.

Comment: This code sends LSB-first

Comment: What value are you receiving? Knowing that would help with troubleshooting.

Comment: I was receiving several different values, not just one consistent value.

Comment: @markrages, yes you're right, the reverse loop order and comment through me

Comment: My apologies for the comment. I adapted this from a different bit banging procedure and forgot to change the comment.

Comment: Doesn't serial have inverted levels?  From wiki: "For data transmission lines (TxD, RxD and their secondary channel equivalents) logic one is defined as a negative voltage" Though this wouldn't explain the fact that received data is changing.  I think stop bit is low too, looking at wiki serial traces.

Comment: Also, the delay is not exactly 1/baud unless writing to port takes no time. Though if you are using 300 baud, the instruction execution speed will be irrelevant.  What clock rate is your PIC running at?

Comment: I'm using a 4MHz internal oscillator. And 9600 baud

Comment: And you are connecting to Arduino's hardware serial TX/RX pins?

Comment: All I'm doing is transmitting from my PIC to the Arduino. So I have my `Tx_Pin` on the PIC connected to Rx on the Arduino.

Comment: @angelatlarge only RS-232 levels are inverted.  At the microcontroller, levels are normal CMOS.

Comment: @markrages Yeah, TTL levels are not inverted (I meant to edit that in after reading some more, but the time limit expired. That's why I asked about the Arduino: if there is something in between the Arduino and the PIC (A max chip? Two max chips?  unlikely, granted) then the levels might be incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While your calculation of 104uS is correct for 9600BPS your loop and the various operations it performs will be adding an additional delay. There are a few ways you could go about tuning the timing:

- Subtract a constant from your uS delay until it starts working. It'd
  probably be best to determine the minimum / maximum number it works
  with and pick the middle value.
- Do something similar using a scope to check the final timing if you have
  one available.
- Look at the assembler output from the compiler and determine how many
  cycles the loop takes.

I also see you're using the RC clock. I normally like to keep my serial timing within 2% for reliable operation so also check to make sure the part has that much stability when using the RC clock for reliable operation.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give some of these suggestions a go in the morning and get back to you.

Comment: I'd agree with PeterJ. I usually have to use an external clock (crystal or resonator) to get accurate data transmission. Plus, the bit twiddling within the loop is adding some time onto your delay.

Comment: So I think I figured it out. I don't think my `uart_time_delay()` routine is delaying at all. I'm using the built in `__delay_us()` method. Any thoughts on this? How can I do a more reliable delay in C? I need it to be 1/baud

Comment: @WillemEllis, I just noticed you have _XTAL_FREQ defined as 4.0 - I think it should be in Hertz so 4000000, that might be doing something odd.

Comment: That was it!!! I am so happy right now! I changed the _XTAL_FREQ to 4000000, and lowered the baud rate to 4800, and it works! Thanks @PeterJ

Comment: @PeterJ, Not sure if you care, but as a payoff, here's what you helped me accomplish! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvSl8_K2UX4